# Typescript: some strange spread allowed that breaks typings

Tags: typescript

Why this works without error:

```
interface S {
  chats: {
    [ChatId: number]: {
      name: string
      messages: []
    }
  }
}

const s1: S = {
  chats: {
    [1123]: {
      name: 'some',
      messages: [],
    },
  },
}

const s2: S = {
  chats: {
    ...s1,
  },
}

console.log('s2', s2)
```

[Ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=22#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrIN4ChnIQCzjAGcAuTHXZAbQGFCwBJAE3JAFcBbAI2gF1y2KlRBxOEcsTBRQAc0rDxxYnFkQyNPguQBfSnr1YEAexBTkxAIzl0AXgq4CRDUKrVLlgEwBmAQ%20HIouLkAOTExuIhADTauEoqahrUfDHCOqm6MYYmZmAWnjbI9q5OJILaAHRVVhnpWHo54QA2EBVNxrIAFGGe0fkAlEA)

This definilty gives illegal result: `s2 { chats: { chats: { '1123': [Object] } } }`

Is it bug or don't understand something?

Comment: That's actually expected behavior. It's a little bit counterintuitive, but a type like `{ [id: number]: {} }` isn't required to have any such properties. Another example is `const x: Record<string, string> = {}` is meant to be valid.

Comment: not required to have what properties? I don't get. `chats: {chats: {}}` won't work but `chats: {    ...s1,  }` why?

Comment: Changing it to `[ChatId: string]:` fixes this. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that all js object keys are actually always strings. But I have no idea how to explain what typescript is really doing here...

Comment: Yes, there seem to be issues in repo already https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37337